# Socket.io Leak - How do I remove this mongoose event listener that is registered onConnect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

I have the following subscribe even happening when a user connects via socket.io:

```
    socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
    console.log('joining room', room.id);
    socket.join(room.id);
    socket.roomName = room.id;

    // Insert sockets below
    require('../api/item/item.socket').register(socket);
  });
```

The "item.socket" code attaches mongoose event handlers for db events (save, delete, etc..) and emits socket messages when they happen. Here is that code:

```
var Item = require('./it');

exports.register = function(socket) {
  Item.schema.post('save', function (doc) {
    console.log("hit save message");
    onSave(socket, doc);
  });
  Item.schema.post('update', function (doc) {
    console.log("hit update message");
    onSave(socket, doc);
  });
  Item.schema.post('remove', function (doc) {
    onRemove(socket, doc);
  });
};

function onSave(socket, doc, cb) {
  socket.emit(doc._id + ':item:save', doc);
}

function onRemove(socket, doc, cb) {
  socket.emit(doc._id + ':item:remove', doc);
}
```

When a client disconnects the following code is executed:

```
function onDisconnect(socket) {
  console.log('disconnected: ' + socket.roomName);
  socket.leave(socket.roomName);
  socket.removeAllListeners("subscribe");
}
```

The basic problem that i'm having is, if a user connects the get that item.socket mongoose handler to send them updates about model changes. When they disconnect (reload page, leave come back, etc..) that even handler never goes away. For instance, I make a change to "item" and I'll get 10 "hit save" messages if I reload the page 10 times.

Ideally when a client leaves the page, that mongoose handler would be destroyed so its not trying to send messages to no one.

EDIT: It's very clear to me that this is an event handler leak.  And basically I need to do something to destroy the handler on disconnect. I need to somehow create a reference to `require('../api/item/item.socket').register(socket);` and then on disconnect unregister it but i can't figure out how to properly do that with the mongoose models and the way i have it set up.

> ```
> function onDisconnect(socket) {
>       console.log('disconnected: ' + socket.roomName);
>       socket.leave(socket.roomName);
>       socket.removeAllListeners("subscribe"); 
>       //destroy handler here
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the insight, sometimes you just stare at a problem to long and realize the answer is straight forward.  I pretty much did what you said, moved to only register the `item.socket` once. However instead of keeping a list of sockets around, we just use the `socket.io` way to just to send messages to the right sockets, code as follows:

```
'use strict';

var Item = require('./item.model');

var log4js = require('log4js');
var logger = log4js.getLogger();

exports.register = function(socketio) {
  Item.schema.post('save', function (doc) {
    logger.debug("hit save message " + doc._id);
    onSave(socketio, doc);
  });
  Item.schema.post('update', function (doc) {
    logger.debug("hit update message");
    onSave(socketio, doc);
  });
  Item.schema.post('remove', function (doc) {
    onRemove(socketio, doc);
  });
};

function onSave(socketio, doc, cb) {
  socketio.sockets.in(doc._id).emit(doc._id + ':item:save', doc);
}

function onRemove(socketio, doc, cb) {
  socketio.sockets.in(doc._id).emit(doc._id + ':item:remove', doc);
}
```

Where `doc._id` is the room a client joins when subscribing. Leak fixed!!! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is as follows.
You could maintain a collection of the sockets that are connected in "item.socket".
"item.socket" would then export functions to add and remove sockets from this collection. So, you would "require" item.socket in your code once and then call its add method with a socket when a connection is established. Similarly you would call its remove method with the socket when it disconnects. Your mongoose event handlers within item.socket should iterate over the collection of sockets and emit messages as applicable.
In case you would "require" the module in such a way that multiple instances are loaded, you might as well attach the socket collection to the global namespace.